# How to Build a recommendation/similarity engine

Tags: c#, full-text-search, sphinx

I am looking for techniques for creating a recommendation engine. I am using the sphinx fulltext engine.

Answer (score 1):

You should really be looking at something that handles relationships.  What you want is something that implements a graph (i.e nodes and edges) then you use graph traversal to find nodes that match your criteria.  That's simplifying it a lot, but recommendation engines are not easy.

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/apis/predict/

Hope this will help you.